# bash + return in the bash script only from function or also in the script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

in bash as all know we can use return 0 , to exit the function and 0 is the std 0

```
function fun1(){
  return 0
}
```

but can we also use return 0 in the script itself not in function ?

as

```
#!/bin/bash

function fun1(){
  return 0
}

function fun2(){
  return 0
}

function fun3(){
  return 0
}
.
.
.
.
.

fun1
fun2
fun3

echo " script ended "


return 0
```

Comment: In bash, it's not necessary to use **both** the "function" keyword and the `()` parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can if that script is sourced.  You might want to do this instead of exit because if you used exit it would also exit out of the shell you are sourcing from where return would not.  If you execute the script directly it would throw an error for the `return` line and continue to execute the rest of the script.

Comment: so exit 0 will kill the pid of the script and retrun 0 will not kill ?

Comment: @yael `return` is _only_ valid in a shell function or in a sourced script.

Comment: when you mean "sourced script." you mean like run the script as source  /tmp/script.bash?

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
if [[ "$0" == "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ]]; then
    # I'm the "main" script
    exit
else
    # I'm being sourced
    return
fi
```